# Hide and show via CSS without duplicating code

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to know if there's a way to hide a div on a certain device and show it on another without duplicating the code and using CSS tricks.

This is what I'm doing right now:

```
<div class="container"> 
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 d-none d-md-block left-panel">
    <div class="box1">Box 1</div>
    <div class="box2">Box 2</div>
    <div class="box3">Box 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 d-none d-md-block right-sidebar">Right Sidebar
        <div class="widget1">Widget 1 </div>
        <div class="widget2">Widget 2 </div>
        <div class="widget3">Widget 3 </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

.left-panel {
float: left; 
background: gray;
width: 400px;
}

.box1,
.box2,
.box3 {
width: 200px;
background: white;
height: 50px;
border: 1px solid red;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.right-sidebar {
background: pink;
float:left;
width: 100px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/p684mz2u/

I'm using Bootstrap 4 for my project.

Now what I want is (from the right sidebar) I want Widget 1 to come above Box 1, Widget 2 between box 1 and 2, and widget 3 between box 2 and 3.

I know I can hide Widget 1 from desktop and tablet and show it on mobile by using display:none and cloning the whole code again on the desired position, but this is the whole point of creating the thread. I do not want to duplicate code but want to achieve this via CSS tricks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only CSS way to do this w/o duplicate code is to keep all the divs in the same parent row. Then use the ordering classes to re-order the layout on smaller screens...

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 bg-pink">
            <div class="row d-md-block">
                <div class="left-panel col-md-8  order-1 float-left">
                    <div class="box1 mt-2">Box 1</div>
                </div>
                <div class="right-sidebar col-md-4 order-0 float-left">Widget 1 </div>
                <div class="right-sidebar col-md-4 order-2 float-left">Widget 2 </div>
                <div class="right-sidebar col-md-4 order-4 float-left">Widget 3 </div>
                <div class="left-panel col-md-8 order-3 float-left">
                    <div class="box2 mt-2 ">Box 2</div>
                </div>
                <div class="left-panel col-md-8 order-5 float-left">
                    <div class="box3 mt-2">Box 3</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/MhJSsHCFOT

Comment: Is it compulsory that all divs must be inside a parent row?

Comment: Yes, since the re-ordering is relative to each other

Comment: Thanks for your help. But after making everything into one row this is the problem I'm facing now: (http://prntscr.com/lkevxe). I only want a right column but for that, I also have to create a left column. What should I do in this case?